# CARTO DB / Adding images using layer.on('featureClick',function(e,latlng,pos,data)

Tags: carto, image, carto-js, modify-interaction-event

Each of my data points have a different image. The images are all loaded in CARTO and the column has a name. I need to call each of the images on click event.

I've been using the

```
layer.on('featureClick',function(e,latlng,pos,data)
```

to get the data from my points but i can't make it work to get the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make sure that your images are stored in a string/character column as a public url (you can use a service such as [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/)). Then you have to create a html template for your infowindow (iw) like this one:

```
    <script type="infowindow/html" id="iw_template">
    <div class="cartodb-popup">
      <a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
       <div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
         <div class="cartodb-popup-header">
           <img style="width: 100%" src="{{url_img}}"></src>
         </div>
         <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
           <h4>Name: </h4>
           <h3>{{content.data.name}}</h3>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="cartodb-popup-tip-container"></div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Finally, after creating a viz or a layer with CARTO.js, you need your layers or sublayers to `setInteraction` to `True` and add the iw:

```
  layer.setInteraction(true);

  cdb.vis.Vis.addInfowindow(
      map, layer, ['cartodb_id','name','url_img'],
      {
         infowindowTemplate: $('#iw_template').html()
      });
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/9e681f3d5ec6b1546ec27c9c68ab4169) you have a working example.

Comment: Hi Ramiro, Thanks for your response! I manage to have that working and to add a toolpit for hover event. THANKS! I would like the infowindow to be position fixed, always on the left side of the screen but I haven't manage to do that. The only example I found on this was doing a fixed box, but don't know how i can make it work with the code you send me.... THANKS! c.

Comment: Happy to help. If you search here typing "carto" and "infobox" you will find an answer as this is a common feature in CARTO.js. [Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210605/41250), you have an example.

Comment: Hi Ramiro, THANKS!   I used that code a couple of days ago but I couldn´t manage to call the images. It worked very well for data that was text but I don´t know how to get the elements when is not text but it´s images.

Comment: I uploaded the images into my host account and wrote the URL  in a column in CARTO. Each row has it's own URL address. All the examples that i found calling element by id were using the specific url of the image and not {{image_url}} that it's what i need because each plotted dot has it's own image. Does this make sense???

Comment: Mine uses `{{url_img}}`, have you tried it?

Comment: YES! and yours works perfectly fine but the infowindow is not in position fixed.... - the other code - layer.on('featureOver',function(e,latlng,pos,data){ - calls elements by ID but all the examples i have come across call text and not images - and the ones that call images have the same image for all the dots.... I don´t know if I am explaining myself...

Comment: Ok, so ask in another question the new issue: adding a fixed infobox showing an image when clicking on a feature.